# Are questions that do not involve any brewing on topic here?

Tags: discussion

[Calculating alcohol percentage after diluting with a sugar syrup](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/16488/12577) - OP is using ready-made, distilled alcohol. He isn't actually brewing anything, just mixing. Should it be considered on or off topic?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, it's … in the stadium. Maybe not on the pitch, but in the stands.

It involves the same sort of things that brewing would, even if it's not directly about fermentation of beverages.

[image]