# Is this question about sweet liqueur off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

[This question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/3059/12609) seems right on the cusp of being on-topic to me.  On one hand, it doesn't really have anything to do with fermentation or homebrewing.  However, this process more or less like making a tincture and doesn't directly involve distillation, so I could see an argument for this process being something that could be useful for brewers wanting to make a fruit extract to add to their homebrew.

Any thoughts on whether this should be considered on-topic?

Comment: The obvious distinction is that homebrew.SE is for the *production* of alcoholic drinks, while alcohol.SE is for the *consumption* of alcoholic drinks.  The referenced question clearly belongs here and not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinion is fairly in line with jsled's answer [here](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/a/405/12609).  At first I was tempted to flag it but now I'm more on the side of leaving it but just knowing that it's basically on the edge of what's acceptable.

Because very similar things are done by homebrewers in a way that I would consider on-topic, I don't think it matters much that the asker's end-goal is not necessarily in line with what the site is aiming for, just that homebrews might find it useful.

Comment: I agree, if it is of use to homebrewers then it is reasonable for it to be on the site.